# Hows does the default model binder know when to update and when to insert?

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to use an edit action to make a linq DB insert in some cases (weird but true).
The viewmodel I am using contains an domain model called Pricelist. PricelistID is required in that domainID and is the PK in the database.

I can fool the ModelBinder by passing in 0 as an ID, but this of course fails when trying to insert.

Under normal circumstances does the ModelBinder know to make an insert if the PK is not supplied when doing db.SaveChanges()?

Comment: Are you using linq to sql?

Comment: I believe that's what it is called, whatever ships with MVC 4.

Comment: I see you're using `SaveChanges()`, so it's probably Entity Framework.  Linq to sql uses `SubmitChanges()`.  I missed that.

Comment: Sorry yes EF. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it is sufficient to simply call db.Pricelists.Add(pricelist); before calling the SaveChanges();